# read the data from database and print it using django

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I have database created by django, but I can't print a text in my page from database. What function I will learn to make that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have elaborated your question with your code samples. Before diving deep into any framework, you should go with tutorials. Django website itself provides you a step by step tutorial for that.
Here are few references:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEcXbeY4_DQ
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the database in respective view function called in views.py in your app; and return the data as context to template so that you will be able to access them and print them.